# Is it possible to reduce the size of a chrome window further than normal?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I would like to be able to reduce the window size of a chrome window to make it easier to view a tiny video playback whilst using other tabs on a laptop.

At the moment, the minimum size takes up a lot of space on the screen. Is it possible to make it smaller, either through a tweak in Chrome or MacOS?

Comment: What size is the window and how small would you like it to be?  What version of macOS and Chrome are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use a PIP extension that can allow you to view almost any video like you could using the Safari browser. You can basically watch the same video regardless of your active desktop. Here's what I [use](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/picture-in-picture-extens/hkgfoiooedgoejojocmhlaklaeopbecg).

The only issue I face is that the PIP doesn't work on fullscreen windows and for such situations I am forced to use Safari.

Comment: glad I could help!